# Missing next button in the Triage queue after a successful "Looks OK" review

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, triage

I am not sure whether this is Triage queue specific, but I have not seen this in other queues lately, e.g. after passing an audit.

I am not sure either whether it is related to the that this was my 20th (last) review in that queue today, but I thought I would mention this as an additional information.

Here is the screenshot to visually see what exactly is missing after completing [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6506777).

[image]

Since I have just come across [another instance of this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6537307), I am now attaching a screenshot about that, too!

[image]

Comment: That's so not a freehand circle.

Comment: @J.Steen: I am offended by your opinion about my freehand!

Comment: Observed today on this item: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6539026 it was my 20-th review though...

Comment: @rene: yes, for me only the 20th item, too, and only if there is the summary (i.e. your vote made the decision).

Comment: I've had the same problem, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283062/62662 . This happened to me when the `Triage` queue was empty (i reviewed the last item, and got the 'Upvote' message). There was no `Next` buttom, because there was no next item. But there was no `The queue has been cleared` message either. Confusing.

Answer (score 3):

You should now be shown a "Next" button, which will proceed to inform you that you're done with review in this queue for the day.