# Upvote suggestion in Triage Queue has no [Next] button

Tags: bug, triage

I'm getting an upvote suggestion in the Triage queue, but there is no `[Next]` button for me to continue triaging:

[image]

Up- or downvoting the question does not make the `[Next]` button appear either.

It may be possible that the Triage queue is empty, but then i would expect the `The queue has been cleared` message.