# "Congratulations!" audit notification does not appear if audit is the 20th review in Triage

Tags: bug, review-audits, triage

The 20th review item in my Triage queue was an audit today, it was a highly upvoted question.

Clicking "Looks Ok" took me to this screen:

> [image]

Whereas I'm used to being first shown the `"Congratulations! This was a test to ...etc"` screen and only then the notification that tells me that I have reached the maximum reviews in the queue for that day.

Is this behaviour of the Triage queue intentional?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280497/missing-next-button-in-the-triage-queue-after-a-successful-looks-ok-review

Comment: @Shog Thanks, so the audit does not matter then - the queue also behaves strangely with the last review item if "looks ok" consensus is reached.