# There is no Next button when reaching 20 posts on the Help & Improvement queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, help-improvement

On the last question of the Help & Improvement review queue, you don't get a  <kbd>Next</kbd> button.
That is confusing until you realise you have done your allowed reviews for the day.

Can we get a <kbd>Next</kbd> button there, that will redirect to the "Thank you for reviewing ..." page?

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, looks like the same issue that occured on the [Triage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280497/missing-next-button-in-the-triage-queue-after-a-successful-looks-ok-review) queue.

Comment: The bug hit me every day for the last 75 days. I think I am going to inject some javascript myself to deal with this.