# End of the Help and Improvement queue is unclear

Tags: bug, help-improvement

While reviewing in the Help and Improvement queue I stumbled upon this situation

[image]

*Click "next" to move on to the next question*. Well, where is "next"?

It didn't take long for me to figure out that I had just finished my 20th review and there was no 'next' review for me anymore today, but it would be nice if I was told that I was done for today, like other review queues do.

Can that be added?

Comment: I'm pressuming this is a bug.

Comment: I'm impressed you managed to get through 20 H&I reviews

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I skipped a lot more posts than I actually edited. Reason is also discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290872/1843331)

Comment: Looks like they just haven't gotten to this one yet: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287815/there-is-no-next-button-when-reaching-20-posts-on-the-help-improvement-queue?rq=1

Comment: My question is 100% duplicate indeed, but neither have answers :-(